# how can I dynamically take users to certain routes based on the service they registered for in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have three services, Tickets, Cards and Certificates, all in services table. the table columns looks like this:\

> user_id, Service, amount_paid, created_at, created_by, transaction_id

this is my route:

```
Route::get('print/enumeration/{id}', 'TransactionController@printEnumeration');
```

I want the user to be taken to a separate page based on the service selected. I know i can use middlewares but I dont have a great knowlegde on how to implement it, any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This is a great way to start with Middlewares: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Answer (score 2):

**First create middleware using**

php artisan make:middleware midlewareName

**Register middleware app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 'name' => \App\Http\Middleware\name::class,
];
```

**now define your middleware  app/Http/Middleware**

example

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole()=="admin") {
        // Redirect...
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
}
```

read docs for more details https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

first, create your middleware by running:

```
php artisan make:middleware ServiceMiddleWare
```

now open the file created in `app/Http/Middleware` directory. inside `handle` method you can place a `switch` statement and set a case per service and define redirects.
do not forget to register your middleware in kernel. take a look at [this document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)